# Debugging in WebStorm and npm

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, intellij-idea, npm, webstorm

I am new to web development (am a backend developer normally).

I am trying to set up a development environment to reflect my current workflow. I develop Java in IntelliJ Ultimate and I like how I can step through and debug.

The current front end development team start npm and then use Chrome developer tool window to debug.

Is there a way to connect WebStorm to this process so that I can set a break point in WebStorm instead of using the Chrome developer tool window?

I have installed the JetBrains extension in Chrome and I cannot find how to do this on their site.

Again, please excuse my ignorance as I am very new to front end development. but if I can get this functionality it would be fantastic.

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Check this page first: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Tutorials ; this one might be useful as well https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/JavaScript+Debugging+in+PhpStorm (sort of repeats what previous have; maybe described a bit differently -- JS debug will be the same for PhpStorm/WebStorm)

Answer (score 1):

Create JavaScript Debug run configuration per instructions at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session#StartingaJavaScriptdebugsession-Startingadebugsessionwhenusingadifferentwebserver, add breakpoints, start your server via npm, then select the configuration above and press Debug.
See also these videos:

- Quick start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-IsnxZpRrQ
- Breakpoints, stepping, watches: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdXoeVRN1JU

Answer (score 0):

You need chrome extension that you already installed here is link also [ExtensionJetBrains IDE Support](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji)

once you install know enable breakpoint
here is the way to do all step you can see shortcut key too

[image]

once you enabled breakpoint then just click near to line number to set breakpoint
[image]
another option go to File-> setting and enable breakpoint

[image]

[image]

when you run your code open inspect as well then you will see this magic :D :)